# Linq Count inside Select, nested, minimizing immediate execution database dependency calls

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, azure

I have a massive LINQ query that fetches information that looks like this:

[image]

In other words, first-level categories, which own second-level categories, which own third level categories. For each category we retrieve the number of listings it contains.

Here is the query:

```
categories = categoryRepository
           .Categories
           .Where(x => x.ParentID == null)
           .Select(x => new CategoryBrowseIndexViewModel
           {
               CategoryID = x.CategoryID, 
               FriendlyName = x.FriendlyName, 
               RoutingName = x.RoutingName, 
               ListingCount = listingRepository
                              .Listings
                              .Where(y => y.SelectedCategoryOneID == x.CategoryID
                                       && y.Lister.Status != Subscription.StatusEnum.Cancelled.ToString())
                              .Count(),

               BrowseCategoriesLevelTwoViewModels = categoryRepository
                    .Categories
                    .Where(a => a.ParentID == x.CategoryID)
                    .Select(a => new BrowseCategoriesLevelTwoViewModel
                    {
                        CategoryID = a.CategoryID,
                        FriendlyName = a.FriendlyName,
                        RoutingName = a.RoutingName,
                        ParentRoutingName = x.RoutingName,
                        ListingCount = listingRepository
                                       .Listings
                                       .Where(n => n.SelectedCategoryTwoID == a.CategoryID
                                                && n.Lister.Status != Subscription.StatusEnum.Cancelled.ToString())
                                       .Count(),

                        BrowseCategoriesLevelThreeViewModels = categoryRepository
                                         .Categories
                                         .Where(b => b.ParentID == a.CategoryID)
                                         .Select(b => new BrowseCategoriesLevelThreeViewModel
                                         {
                                             CategoryID = b.CategoryID,
                                             FriendlyName = b.FriendlyName,
                                             RoutingName = b.RoutingName,
                                             ParentRoutingName = a.RoutingName,
                                             ParentParentID = x.CategoryID,
                                             ParentParentRoutingName = x.RoutingName,
                                             ListingCount = listingRepository
                                                            .Listings
                                                            .Where(n => n.SelectedCategoryThreeID == b.CategoryID
                                                                     && n.Lister.Status != Subscription.StatusEnum.Cancelled.ToString())
                                                            .Count()
                                         })
                                         .Distinct()
                                         .OrderBy(b => b.FriendlyName)
                                         .ToList()
                    })
                    .Distinct()
                    .OrderBy(a => a.FriendlyName)
                    .ToList()
           })
           .Distinct()
           .OrderBy(x => x.FriendlyName == jobVacanciesFriendlyName)
           .ThenBy(x => x.FriendlyName == servicesLabourHireFriendlyName)
           .ThenBy(x => x.FriendlyName == goodsEquipmentFriendlyName)
           .ToList();
```

This was fast enough on my dev machine, but alas! Deployed to Azure it's very slow. The reason seems to be that this query is making hundreds of dependency calls to the database, I'm pretty sure because of the immediate execution of the Count statements. Although the app and the database are in the same datacenter, the calls add up in a way they didn't on my dev machine (~40s vs < 1s). So what I'd like to do is send this whole thing off to the database, let it crunch, and get it all back in one hit, if it's possible. How do I do this? Also if I'm approaching this whole thing wrong please tell me. This is the biggest bottleneck in my web app so any help to make it more efficient is appreciated. Thank you! (I'm less concerned about web app memory usage than I am about the cumulative effect of all the database calls.)

Comment: Can you include simplified models for classes from your repositories used?

Comment: It may or may not make a difference, but consider doing: `var allCategories = categoryRepository.Categories.ToList();` and `var allListings = listingRepository.Listings.ToList();` beforehand, then performing your queries on the list. Using local memory to store a copy might be faster in performance rather than accessing the database multiple times inside the query.

Comment: Try removing all `Distict` operators - they look redundant and may affect the performance. Also try replacing `Subscription.StatusEnum.Cancelled.ToString()` with string constant like "Cancelled".

Comment: @raderick from the ListingRepository class: `private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();` and `public IEnumerable<Listing> Listings { get { return context.Listings; } }`. It's absolutely stock-standard Entity Framework stuff. Note that I used an IEnumerable. Hope that helps.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL combined with projection, that's exactly what I'm going to do. I'm having trouble making the query behave, i.e. I'm, trying to make it fetch all the data in one hit. Want to have a go at modifying the query in the question to make it visit the database only once?

Comment: @raderick I have actually made the page load very quickly doing what Keyur PATEL suggested (but with projection), but before that hit this error after I made everything IQueryable as Sampath suggested: `The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.` I'm still curious if I can get all the data back in one database call. At the moment I have two (but my query now has less code and is more readable and efficient. Pretty happy with the result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've got so far. It's working really well, but I'm still curious if I can do this in one DB trip, not two. That would seem to be complicated by the fact that each repository has its own DBContext. If you guys have any more thoughts I'd be more than happy to upvote you.

```
var allCategories = categoryRepository
                    .Categories
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        x.CategoryID,
                        x.FriendlyName,
                        x.RoutingName,
                        x.ParentID
                    })
                    .ToList();

var allListings = listingRepository
                  .Listings
                  .Where(x => x.Lister.Status != Subscription.StatusEnum.Cancelled.ToString())
                  .Select(x => new
                  {
                      x.SelectedCategoryOneID,
                      x.SelectedCategoryTwoID,
                      x.SelectedCategoryThreeID,                                      
                  })
                  .ToList();

            categories = 
            allCategories
           .Where(x => x.ParentID == null)
           .Select(a => new CategoryBrowseIndexViewModel
           {
               CategoryID = a.CategoryID,
               FriendlyName = a.FriendlyName,
               RoutingName = a.RoutingName,
               ListingCount = allListings
                              .Where(x => x.SelectedCategoryOneID == a.CategoryID)
                              .Count(),

               BrowseCategoriesLevelTwoViewModels = 
                    allCategories
                    .Where(x => x.ParentID == a.CategoryID)
                    .Select(b => new BrowseCategoriesLevelTwoViewModel
                    {
                        CategoryID = b.CategoryID,
                        FriendlyName = b.FriendlyName,
                        RoutingName = b.RoutingName,
                        ParentRoutingName = a.RoutingName,
                        ListingCount = allListings
                                       .Where(x => x.SelectedCategoryTwoID == b.CategoryID)
                                       .Count(),

                        BrowseCategoriesLevelThreeViewModels = 
                            allCategories
                            .Where(x => x.ParentID == b.CategoryID)
                            .Select(c => new BrowseCategoriesLevelThreeViewModel
                            {
                                CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                                FriendlyName = c.FriendlyName,
                                RoutingName = c.RoutingName,
                                ParentRoutingName = b.RoutingName,
                                ParentParentID = a.CategoryID,
                                ParentParentRoutingName = a.RoutingName,
                                ListingCount = allListings
                                               .Where(x => x.SelectedCategoryThreeID == c.CategoryID)
                                               .Count()
                            })
                            .OrderBy(x => x.FriendlyName)
                    })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.FriendlyName)
           })
           .OrderBy(x => x.FriendlyName == jobVacanciesFriendlyName)
           .ThenBy(x => x.FriendlyName == servicesLabourHireFriendlyName)
           .ThenBy(x => x.FriendlyName == goodsEquipmentFriendlyName);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion to your massive query.

1. **Don't** use `ToList()` inside the inner queries.
2. **Don't** use `Count()` inside the inner queries.

Try to retrieve all the data `once` without above `IEnumerable` operations.In other words fetch the data as `IQueryable` mode.After loading it in to the App's memory,you can create your data model as you wish.This process will give huge performance boost to your app.So try that and let us know.

**Update :** about `Count()`

If you have lot of columns on that list, just fetch a 1 column without `Count()` using `projection`.After that you can get the `count()` on your `IEnumerable` list.In other words on your app's memory after fetching it from the `db`.

Comment: Totally agree about the ToList(), I actually had everything as IQueryable initially, the difference is surprisingly not that great (still takes a very long time). I just had the idea of, instead of forcing a count on a listing (which I did because a listing can be very big and contain lots of data), just Selecting the smallest piece of data I can about a listing e.g. a true/false field. That way I don't use too much memory, and can run the Counts in the app. What do you think? I'll try this in the morning.

Comment: I'm still not sure how I construct the query to make sure it only retrieves the data once? Could you please modify the query so I know what you would do? I think I'm missing something simple. Thanks for your help so far